# Неверные данные при парсинге Json файла

Tags: java, json

Пытаюсь парсить следующий файл (artist.json):

```
[
  {
    "artistName": "Camila Cabello",
    "trackName": "Shameless",
    "arCurSong_artistName": "Camila Cabello",
    "arCurSong_trackName": "Shameless"
  },
  {
    "wrapperType": "track",
    "kind": "song",
    "artistId": 101927659,
    "collectionId": 1459858945,
    "trackId": 1459859309,
    "artistName": "\u0420\u0443\u043a\u0438 \u0412\u0432\u0435\u0440\u0445",
    "collectionName": "\u041e\u043d\u0430 \u043c\u0435\u043d\u044f \u0446\u0435\u043b\u0443\u0435\u0442 - Single",
    "trackName": "\u041e\u043d\u0430 \u043c\u0435\u043d\u044f \u0446\u0435\u043b\u0443\u0435\u0442",
    "collectionCensoredName": "\u041e\u043d\u0430 \u043c\u0435\u043d\u044f \u0446\u0435\u043b\u0443\u0435\u0442 - Single",
    "trackCensoredName": "\u041e\u043d\u0430 \u043c\u0435\u043d\u044f \u0446\u0435\u043b\u0443\u0435\u0442",
    "artistViewUrl": "https:\/\/music.apple.com\/ru\/artist\/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85\/101927659?uo=4",
    "collectionViewUrl": "https:\/\/music.apple.com\/ru\/album\/%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82\/1459858945?i=1459859309\u0026uo=4",
    "trackViewUrl": "https:\/\/music.apple.com\/ru\/album\/%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82\/1459858945?i=1459859309\u0026uo=4",
    "previewUrl": "https:\/\/audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com\/itunes-assets\/AudioPreview113\/v4\/ee\/42\/92\/ee429274-d3e7-86eb-cbc2-7c22a32f5e68\/mzaf_4516252296251182752.plus.aac.p.m4a",
    "artworkUrl30": "https:\/\/is5-ssl.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music113\/v4\/60\/ab\/a7\/60aba708-839e-d8f1-bf62-e5d42a4f2b54\/source\/30x30bb.jpg",
    "artworkUrl60": "https:\/\/is5-ssl.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music113\/v4\/60\/ab\/a7\/60aba708-839e-d8f1-bf62-e5d42a4f2b54\/source\/60x60bb.jpg",
    "artworkUrl100": "https:\/\/is5-ssl.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music113\/v4\/60\/ab\/a7\/60aba708-839e-d8f1-bf62-e5d42a4f2b54\/source\/100x100bb.jpg",
    "collectionPrice": 22,
    "trackPrice": 22,
    "releaseDate": "2019-04-24T07:00:00Z",
    "collectionExplicitness": "notExplicit",
    "trackExplicitness": "notExplicit",
    "discCount": 1,
    "discNumber": 1,
    "trackCount": 1,
    "trackNumber": 1,
    "trackTimeMillis": 231027,
    "country": "RUS",
    "currency": "RUB",
    "primaryGenreName": "\u041f\u043e\u043f",
    "isStreamable": true,
    "arCurSong_artistName": "\u0420\u0443\u043a\u0438 \u0412\u0432\u0435\u0440\u0445",
    "arCurSong_trackName": "\u041e\u043d\u0430 \u041c\u0435\u043d\u044f \u0426\u0435\u043b\u0443\u0435\u0442"
  },
  {
    "wrapperType": "track",
    "kind": "song",
    "artistId": 280215834,
    "collectionId": 1484659425,
    "trackId": 1484659435,
    "artistName": "\u0421\u0435\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0430 \u0413\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0441",
    "collectionName": "Look At Her Now - Single",
    "trackName": "Look At Her Now",
    "collectionCensoredName": "Look At Her Now - Single",
    "trackCensoredName": "Look At Her Now",
    "artistViewUrl": "https:\/\/music.apple.com\/ru\/artist\/%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81\/280215834?uo=4",
    "collectionViewUrl": "https:\/\/music.apple.com\/ru\/album\/look-at-her-now\/1484659425?i=1484659435\u0026uo=4",
    "trackViewUrl": "https:\/\/music.apple.com\/ru\/album\/look-at-her-now\/1484659425?i=1484659435\u0026uo=4",
    "previewUrl": "https:\/\/audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com\/itunes-assets\/AudioPreview113\/v4\/9a\/3c\/29\/9a3c293a-e0c2-4075-0170-54cb0917b53f\/mzaf_3382791093435540284.plus.aac.p.m4a",
    "artworkUrl30": "https:\/\/is2-ssl.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music123\/v4\/10\/5e\/9e\/105e9ec9-60b3-6489-2cc2-c7a4c951cfeb\/source\/30x30bb.jpg",
    "artworkUrl60": "https:\/\/is2-ssl.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music123\/v4\/10\/5e\/9e\/105e9ec9-60b3-6489-2cc2-c7a4c951cfeb\/source\/60x60bb.jpg",
    "artworkUrl100": "https:\/\/is2-ssl.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music123\/v4\/10\/5e\/9e\/105e9ec9-60b3-6489-2cc2-c7a4c951cfeb\/source\/100x100bb.jpg",
    "collectionPrice": 22,
    "trackPrice": 22,
    "releaseDate": "2019-10-24T07:00:00Z",
    "collectionExplicitness": "notExplicit",
    "trackExplicitness": "notExplicit",
    "discCount": 1,
    "discNumber": 1,
    "trackCount": 1,
    "trackNumber": 1,
    "trackTimeMillis": 162596,
    "country": "RUS",
    "currency": "RUB",
    "primaryGenreName": "\u041f\u043e\u043f",
    "isStreamable": true,
    "arCurSong_artistName": "Selena Gomez",
    "arCurSong_trackName": "Look At Her Now"
  }
]
```

Для этого создал проект с несколькими классами:

```
public class Artist {
    private String artistName;
    private String trackName;

    public String getArtistName(){
        return artistName;
    }

    public void setArtistName(String artistName) {
        this.artistName = artistName;
    }

    public String getTrackName() {
        return trackName;
    }

    public void setTrackName(String trackName) {
        this.trackName = trackName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

       if (this.artistName!=null){
       sb.append(this.artistName);}

       if (this.trackName!=null){
       sb.append(this.trackName);}

       return sb.toString();

       }

}

public class ReadJSONExample {

public static Artist readArtistJSONFile(Context context) throws IOException,JSONException {
        String jsonText = readText(context,R.raw.artist);
        JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(jsonText);

        String artist_name = jsonRoot.getString("artistName");
        String track_name = jsonRoot.getString("trackName");

        Artist artist = new Artist();
        artist.setArtistName(artist_name);
        artist.setTrackName(track_name);
        return artist;
    }

    private static String readText(Context context,int resId) throws IOException{
        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String s=null;
        while ((s=br.readLine())!=null){
        sb.append(s);
        sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText outputText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        outputText = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    }

    public void Runexample(View view) throws IOException, JSONException {
        try {
            Artist artist = ReadJSONExample.readArtistJSONFile(this);
            outputText.setText(artist.toString());
            }   catch(Exception e){
                outputText.setText(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }

}
```

XML-разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Run Example"
        android:onClick="Runexample"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.347" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

В итоге хотел получить строку вида: "Camila Cabello - Shameless", а
получилось следующее:
[image: результат кода]

Направьте в нужное русло, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Если особо не хотите думать, то сделайте так:

1. Открываете сайт [jsonschema2pojo.org](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)
2. Копипастите туда ваш json
3. Настраиваете выдачу в Java
4. Копипастите Java исходники к себе
5. Чуток шаманите
6. Профит

Comment: Хорошо. Немного времени и отпишусь, как все прошло. Но у меня есть мысль, что путаю массив с данными при формировании конечного результата.

Comment: Я попробовал ваш метод, он работает точно так же. Отображение данных одинаковое на экране. Как мне получить строку в виде Artist Name + Track Name? Без сервисных ответов?